# Qualify KnockOutJS attributes in XHTML (via XML namespace)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, xml-namespaces

I'd like to be able to qualify the KnockOutJS attributes in my XHTML documents.

Here is what I want to do:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:ko="http://knockoutjs.com"> <!-- Supply the KnockOutJS namespace here -->
  <head>
    <script th:src="@{/js/lib/knockout-2.2.1.js}" src="../../js/lib/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <!-- Remainder omitted... -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      My name is:
      <span ko:data-bind="text: name"></span><!-- Problem line - KnockOut will ignore data-bind when it's qualified -->
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above example doesn't work as KnockOutJS ignores the qualified `ko:data-bind`. Obviously, if I remove the `ko:` then it works.

Is there a way to tell KnockOutJS that it's qualified and what the qualifier is, please?

The reasons I want to qualify KnockOutJS attributes are:

1. Validation. I get a lot of validation warnings (in the IDE) about undefined attributes.
2. Clarity. We (sparingly) use Thymeleaf for server-side templating, and Thymeleaf works similarly to KnockOut in that it's specified as HTML attributes also. It would be nice to have Thymeleaf qualified with th, KnockOut qualified as ko, and leave standard HTML unqualified.

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I changed updated my HTML files so that they don't use the Thymelead/XHTML DOCTYPE and instead use the HTML5 DOCTYPE: `<!DOCTYPE html>`. All is working nicely now (except KnockOut is unqualified!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knockout supports custom binding providers that can be used to retrieve bindings however you want. This isn't currently documented officially, but is [described on Ryan Niemeyer's web site](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/09/ko-13-preview-part-2-custom-binding.html).

Here is a binding provider that extends the built-in one to add support for `ko:data-bind`.

```
var originalNodeHasBindings = ko.bindingProvider.instance.nodeHasBindings;
var originalGetBindings = ko.bindingProvider.instance.getBindings;
ko.utils.extend(ko.bindingProvider.instance, {
    nodeHasBindings: function(node) {
        if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.hasAttribute('ko:data-bind'))
            return true;
        return originalNodeHasBindings.call(this, node);
    },
    getBindings: function(node, bindingContext) {
        if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.hasAttribute('ko:data-bind'))
            return this.parseBindingsString(node.getAttribute('ko:data-bind'), bindingContext, node);
        return originalGetBindings.call(this, node, bindingContext);
    }
});
```

Example of usage: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/vSQkW/

Answer (score 1):

According to the knockoutjs support forums, this isn't supported and is not expected to be supported in the future

[KO forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/knockoutjs/9M9vVLIEDvQ)

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but thanks anyway! (I swear I've been Googling for about an hour looking for this... Good link!)

Comment: That's an old post. Knockout now supports custom binding providers that can be used to retrieve bindings in whatever way you want.

Comment: @MichaelBest  Not seeing any documentation for that.  I know custom bindings, but those still use data-bind.  Can you show what you mean?  If you've got something I'll definitely upvote the answer

Comment: @ben336 Shifted the accepted answer from you to Michael Best. Hope you don't mind!